# How to retrieve a list of ALL completed documents in docu-sign using laravel api

Tags: docusignapi

this is my code

```
public function getCompletedDocuments()
    {
        $token = VendorDocusignRecord::where(['user_id'=>1])->first();
        $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
        $config->setHost(env('DOCUSIGN_BASE_URL'));
        $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token->access_token);

        $apiClient = new \DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
        $envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

        try {
            $envelopes = $envelopesApi->listStatusChanges($token->account_id,'completed');
            return $envelopes->getEnvelopes();
        } catch (ApiException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

i want to get the all my completed documetns but when i call this function docusign give me erros

DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi::listStatusChanges(): Argument #2 ($options) must be of type ?DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi\ListStatusChangesOptions, string given,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must specify a date. I went 30 days back here, if you need more - change the code as you like.

```
  public function getCompletedDocuments()
    {
        $token = VendorDocusignRecord::where(['user_id'=>1])->first();
        $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
        $config->setHost(env('DOCUSIGN_BASE_URL'));
        $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token->access_token);

        $apiClient = new \DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
        $envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

        try {
        $from_date = date("c", (time() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)));
        $options = new ListStatusChangesOptions();
        $options->setFromDate($from_date);            $envelopes = 
        $envelopesApi->listStatusChanges($token->account_id,'completed', $options);
            return $envelopes->getEnvelopes();
        } catch (ApiException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi::listStatusChanges(): Argument #2 ($options) must be of type ?DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi\ListStatusChangesOptions, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\docusignDocuments\app\Http\Controllers\DocusignController.php on line 225

Comment: I have tried your code, but I encountered an error.

Comment: What was the error Moshin?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution now.

```
$token = VendorDocusignRecord::where(['user_id'=>1])->first();
$config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
            $config->setHost(env('DOCUSIGN_BASE_URL'));
            $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token->access_token);

            $apiClient = new \DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
            $envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
            try {
                $options = new EnvelopesApi\ListStatusChangesOptions();
                $options->setFromDate('2021-01-01');
                $options->setStatus('completed');
                $options->setOrder('desc');
                $envelopes = $envelopesApi->listStatusChanges(env('DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID'), $options);
            
                $envelopeData = $envelopes->getEnvelopes();
                return view('docusign.get_list', compact('envelopeData'));
            } catch (\DocuSign\eSign\ApiException $e) {
                return view('error')->with('message', 'An error occurred while retrieving the envelope list. Please try again later.');
            }
```